# android AES decrypt files: BadPaddingException: EVP_CipherFinal_ex

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

I am recently working on file encryption / decryption.

BadPaddingException: EVP_CipherFinal_ex: always occurs when I try to decrypt the file with the same key.

Code snippets will be posted below.

Am I doing something wrong?

thank you for your helps.

Encrypt

```
public static void encryptFile() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + TARGET_FILE);

    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];

    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec("1234567890123456".getBytes());

    byte[] key = "only for testing".getBytes();
    MessageDigest sha;
    try {
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + ENCRYPT_FILE);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

        //CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(fileOutputStream, cipher);

        int read;

        while ((read = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "encrypt read= " + read);

            byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(buffer);
            if (encryptedData != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "encrypted size= " + encryptedData.length);
                fileOutputStream.write(encryptedData, 0, read);
            }

            //cipherOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }
        //cipherOutputStream.flush();
        //cipherOutputStream.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException
            | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException
            | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Decrypt

```
public static void decryptFile() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + ENCRYPT_FILE);

    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];

    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec("1234567890123456".getBytes());

    byte[] key = "only for testing".getBytes();
    MessageDigest sha;
    try {
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + DECRYPT_FILE);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

        //CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(fileInputStream, cipher);

        int read;

        while ((read = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "decrypt read= " + read);

            byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(buffer);
            if (decryptedData != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "decrypted size= " + decryptedData.length);
                fileOutputStream.write(decryptedData, 0, read);
            }

            //fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        //cipherInputStream.close();
        fileInputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException
            | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException
            | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

btw: It will work properly when I use CipherInputStream / CipherOutStream. I want to know if it is possible to use just FileInputStream / FileOutputStream only? thank you.

Edited:
Encrypt function will enlarge byte array about 16 bytes, I've tried increase the buffer size of decryption and still can't get it work.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8 + 16];
```

Log:

I/#_: decrypt read= 8208

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: EVP_CipherFinal_ex

at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_CipherFinal_ex(Native Method)

at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.doFinalInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:430)

at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:466)

at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1340)

at CryptoHelper.decryptFile(CryptoHelper.java:128)

**Edited** Update code here based on #Robert's answer for anyone who encountered the same problems like I did.

Encrypt:

```
int read;

        while ((read = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "encrypt read= " + read);
            byte[] encryptedData = cipher.update(buffer, 0, read);
            //byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(buffer);
            if (encryptedData != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "encrypted size= " + encryptedData.length);
                fileOutputStream.write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.length);
            }

            //cipherOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }
        byte[] finals = cipher.doFinal();
        Log.i(TAG, "encrypted finals = " + finals.length);
        fileOutputStream.write(finals, 0, finals.length);
```

Decrypt:

```
int read;

        while ((read = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "decrypt read= " + read);

            //byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(buffer);
            byte[] decryptedData = cipher.update(buffer, 0, read);
            if (decryptedData != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "decrypted size= " + decryptedData.length);
                fileOutputStream.write(decryptedData, 0, decryptedData.length);
            }

            //fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }
        byte[] finals = cipher.doFinal();
        Log.i(TAG, "decrypted finals = " + finals.length);
        fileOutputStream.write(finals, 0, finals.length);
```

Thanks again for Robert's help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that you are always calling `cipher.doFinal()` for each block of data which is wrong as each block will be padded.

If you are en/decrypting data block-wise use `cipher.update(...)` and after the last block has been processed only call `cipher.doFinal()` once.

The easier way would be to use a CipherInputStream/CipherOutputStream - it does exactly what I have described for you (doFinal is called when you close the stream).

Comment: I followed your answer and edited the code. It works now. Big thanks for your help. You saved my day.